# OpenCv cvArcLength function equivalent in matlab

Tags: matlab, opencv

i found a code in Opencv but I'm doing mi project in Matlab, somebody know how can i do this instruction in matlab?

```
gf_P = cvArcLength(contours);
```

Thank you for any help you can provide in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`arclength.m`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34871-arclength/content/arclength.m), which is able to compute the arc length of a general curve in any number of dimensions